# How to find Free world city database in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

Does anybody know where I can find open source world city database that includes:

- city names in different languages
- region / state / province
- country
- IP address range
- longitude / latitude

Comment: Freebase offers free location data, however, I'm not sure if they offer IP address range

https://www.freebase.com/location

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For everywhere except the US, try the [National Geospatial Intelligence Agency's GNS Country Files](http://geonames.nga.mil/gns/html/) dataset  and for the USA, use the [USGS Domestic Names Database](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/board-on-geographic-names/domestic-names). This data is copyright free and relatively easy to import into MySQL.

These do not include IP address ranges, that sort of data is commercially available from folks like [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/city)

Comment: +1: For MaxMind. I use them in couple of projects and their IP data is really accurate.

Comment: Where is USA database? i cannot find that in the link you provided.

Comment: I did write that 9 years ago. Link updated.

Answer (score 3):

MaxMind's GeoLite City database is free:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

The website has instructions for inserting the contents into a database table.

It contains city, region/state/province, country, IP address range, latitude, longitude and a bunch more info.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.rocky.nu/software/mysql-world-locations-database

This one contains world cities and Latitude / Longitude

You can also get a world database at geonames org